# How to update the source code of a module per chunk?

Tags: parsing, webpack, abstract-syntax-tree, webpack-plugin

Recently, I started learning how to build webpack plugins. I'm trying to build a plugin that will update my source code.

The rules are simple:

1. If the **entry point** name has less than 2 `a`s, I have to rename all the variables `haha` to `hehe` in all modules in the chunk of the said **entry point**.
2. If the **entry point** name has more than 2 `a`s, I have to rename all the variables `haha` to `hoho` of all modules in the chunk of the said **entry point**.

This is my code:

*a.js*

```
const haha = 'hello';
// will be "const hehe = 'hello';" in the bundle of "aa" entry point
// will be "const hoho = 'hello';" in the bundle of "aaaa" entry point
console.log(haha);
// will be "console.log(hehe);" in the bundle of "aa" entry point
// will be "console.log(hoho);" in the bundle of "aaaa" entry point
export default haha;
// will be "export default hehe;" in the bundle of "aa" entry point
// will be "export default hoho;" in the bundle of "aaaa" entry point
```

*few.js*

```
import haha from 'a'; // will be "import hehe from 'a';" in the bundle
console.log(haha); // will be "console.log(hehe);" in the bundle
```

*lots.js*

```
import haha from 'a'; // will be "import hoho from 'a';" in the bundle
console.log(haha); // will be "console.log(hoho);" in the bundle
```

*webpack.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
 mode: 'development',
 entry: {
    aa: 'few.js',
    aaaa: 'lots.js'
 },
 output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
 }
};
```

I don't know exactly what the proper way to do that.

At the beginning, I thought that my plugin has to register to a specific hook of the parser, check the name of the current **entry point** and replace the name of the AST node. The problem is that the module `a.js` is parsed only once.

The second way I tried is to register to the `render` hook of the `mainTemplate` and rename variables via a simple regex. I don't like this method since code replacing via regex is extremely difficult (IMO).

What do you think? What is the proper way to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8087). Response from [Tobias Koppers](https://github.com/sokra):

> That's not possible.
>
> The modules are independent from the original entrypoint. The module
>   graph doesn't contain this information. In addition to that modules
>   can be in both entrypoints, but are not build twice in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Ya right. You can't get entry info in modules. 
    I think you can solve may be in other way not using entry point. 
    As modules are cached once it is loaded, 
    we can make use of inline resource query

**a.js**

```
    const haha = 'hello';
    console.log(haha);
    export default haha;
```

**few.js**

```
    import haha from './a?change=e'; // will be "import hehe from 'a';" in the bundle
    console.log(haha); // will be "console.log(hehe);" in the bundle
```

**lots.js**

```
    import haha from './a?change=o'; // will be "import hehe from 'a';" in the bundle
    console.log(haha); // will be "console.log(hoho);" in the bundle
```

custom loader -> **transformer.js**

```
    module.exports = function(source) {
      let queryval = "";
      if (this.resourceQuery && this.resourceQuery.indexOf('change')) {
        queryval = this.resourceQuery.substr(this.resourceQuery.indexOf("change"+ 1));
        // console.log("queryval: ", queryval);
        if (queryval) {
          const replacedCode = source.replace(/[a]/g, queryval); // this replace every thing but need own logic even default -> def_ult _ is query val :P
          console.log("replacedCode: ", replacedCode);
          return replacedCode;
        }
      }
      return source;
    }
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
    const path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
        mode: 'development',
        entry: {
            aa: './src/few.js',
            aaaa: './src/lots.js'
        },
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.js$/,
                oneOf: [
                  {
                    resourceQuery: /change/,
                    use: [
                      {
                        loader: path.resolve('./src/transformer.js'),
                        options: {
                          replaceWith: true
                        }
                      }
                    ],
                  },
                  {
                    loader: path.resolve('./src/transformer.js'),
                  }
                ],
            }
          ]
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
        },
        optimization: {
          runtimeChunk: "single"
        }
    };
```